# How to programmatically write a value to a variable in my .env file?

Tags: node.js, dotenv

So for my Node.js app I created a seed script that can be called from the command line.
This creates a user and a password based on a JWT secret.
When running the script I want the secret to be a custom generated string and write it to the `APP_SECRET` variable in my `.env` file.
Is there any way to programmatically fill the variable with this custom string in the `.env` file?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Read the file, replace whatever value is after APP_SECRET= and write the file back to the file system. Another option is to use a .env template file, or maybe just append to the end of the file the new value, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, you need do 2 things: generate random string and write it to your .env file.

1. For generating random string use [npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/randomstring) or your handmade generator based on [node crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html).
2. Than use `fs` nodule to write variable to file.
   For example,

   ```
   fs.appendFileSync('.env', 'APP_SECRET=var');
   ```

   or

   ```
   fs.appendFile('.env', 'APP_SECRET=var', function (err) {
      if (err) throw err;
   });
   ```

However, this would append string to file. If you want replace ENV variable every time, use `fs.writefile()`.